# Join divided shape in Illustrator 2020

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, shapes, gradient, fill

I want to fill this shape with a gradient, but because it's divided it won't fill it completely, leaving a gap between subshapes.

How can I join these subshapes? I can't use pathfinder because it will just create another stroke between subshapes, but won't fill the gap.

Fill tool doesn't really work here: It fills the gap, but if I try to divide this shape once again, the fill color will just vanish.

[image: Without fill color]
[image: With fill color]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate object of the same size and approximate shape, apply the gradient you need, then push that new object behind the black outline shape via 'Send to Back' or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>.